# Why this return org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException?

Tags: java, h2

I want to set up a counter to take the number of records from the database :

```
String sql = " select count(*) as counter from CLIENT ";
conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
try {
    state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    result = state.executeQuery();

    Counter=result.getInt("counter");
    txtUser.setText("user"+(Integer.toString(Counter)));

}
catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why this code throw an `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException` ?

Comment: give us the stacktrace. it will be printed with that line e1.printStackTrace();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After

```
result = state.executeQuery();
```

you also need to call

```
result.next();
```

to advance the current row pointer.

If `result.next();` returns `false`, no row is available.

Comment: thanks a lot . I know there are records in the database and I guess it could have been result.next();

Comment: @S.Iliev it's something you always risk forgetting about when dealing with single row results. Just think about the ResultSet as a cursor which doesn't point to anything valid in the beginning.